# Text displayed out of the graph pane

Tags: c#, zedgraph

Is there a way to not display objects out of the graph pane, as shown on the picture below?

[image: ZedGraph screenshot]

I use `GraphPane.AddCurve()` to add the curves and `GraphPane.GraphObjList.Add(new TextObj(...))` to add the texts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do it, I think you have to create a new TextObj so that you can modify the "IsClippedToChartRect" attribute.

```
ZedGraph.TextObj text = new ZedGraph.TextObj("Hello", xloc, yloc);

text.IsClippedToChartRect = true;
```